# How to create a sub report when I click on Particular sector of Pie chart in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services

I have the requirement to generate chart in SSRS 2008 and clicking on specific region of chart I need to generate sub report. I am already done with pie chart and the report but not able to generate the sub-report dynamically

[image]

I need to generate different reports when I click on different bars in bar graph

can anyone help with that

Comment: You can't dynamically generate sub-reports, but you can dynamically unhide them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **Subreport** is a report already embedded in the report.

I think what you want is actually a **Drill Through** report where you click on an item and a new report pops up showing you the detail of whatever data you just clicked on.

You'll need to create a new report with a table. If your query has the detail you need, you can re-use the same query otherwise you need to create a query to show the detail you want.

You'll need to a parameter to filter for the value you select from your chart. Your chart says **Emp_ID** but I am guessing that's just a count and you really want the **text** from the X axis (i.e. *Deliver Client projects...* ) - your employee's Experience.

When you've created the drill through report with the parameter for the field, go back to the main report and add an **ACTION**. Specify your new drill through report, Add the parameter by selecting it in the Name drop down and select the field you want to get the value from (the category Group field from the bar chart).

Now when you click on a bar, your new subreport will open with the detail filtered by the field you click on. If you click on the bar for *Delivered Client Projects and proficient*, your new report with a table of the 31 employees will appear.

Here's some more detailed info:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337477(v=sql.105).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519554.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to have already made the sub-reports and set your chart elements to load that report on their click through properties - **You cannot simply *generate* a report by clicking on a report element**.

If you want to go to different reports depending on data behind the pie chart section that is clicked on, you can set that up either in your original dataset with a column for which report to load or you can add a `switch` statement in the expression for the address of the report to load.  To handle your parameters, this is probably easiest done with URL addressing.